# How to transfer object from one activity to another using parcelable? 

Tags: android, android-activity, parcelable

I am transferring an object from one activity to another using parcelable, but it showing null
as retrieving that object in another activity.
any suggestions?

Here's the code :

```
public class TPackage implements Parcelable {

// private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int cost;
private String name;
private int totalChannels;
private HashMap<String, Channel> channelList;

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public int getTotal_channels() {
    return totalChannels;
}

public void setTotal_channels(int total_channels) {
    this.totalChannels = total_channels;
}

public HashMap<String, Channel> getList() {
    return channelList;
}

public void setList(HashMap<String, Channel> list) {
    this.channelList = list;
}

public void put(String name, Channel c) {
    channelList.put(name, c);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<TPackage> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TPackage>() {
    public TPackage createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new TPackage();
    }

    public TPackage[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TPackage[size];
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This is the right way to transfer your object using parcel andorid

```
public class TPackage implements Parcelable {

// private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int cost;
private String name;
private int totalChannels;
private HashMap<String, Channel> channelList;

public TPackage(int cost, String name, int totalChannels,
        HashMap<String, Channel> channelList){
    this.cost = cost;
    this.name = name;
    this.totalChannels = totalChannels;
    this.channelList = channelList;
}


public TPackage(Parcel in){
    //same order as that in writeToParcel()
    cost = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    totalChannels = in.readInt();
    Bundle bundle = in.readBundle();
    channelList = (HashMap<String, Channel>) bundle.getSerializable("channelList");
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public int getTotal_channels() {
    return totalChannels;
}

public void setTotal_channels(int total_channels) {
    this.totalChannels = total_channels;
}

public HashMap<String, Channel> getList() {
    return channelList;
}

public void setList(HashMap<String, Channel> list) {
    this.channelList = list;
}

public void put(String name, Channel c) {
    channelList.put(name, c);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(cost);
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeInt(totalChannels);
    //easiest way to transfer HashMap via parcel
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("channelList", channelList);
    dest.writeBundle(bundle);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<TPackage> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<TPackage>() {
    public TPackage createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new TPackage(in);
    }

    public TPackage[] newArray(int size) {
        return new TPackage[size];
    }
};

}
```

[EDITED]
This is the sender activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TPackage tPackage = new TPackage(10, "hello", 123, new HashMap<String, Channel>());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("parcel", tPackage);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the receiver activity

```
public class NActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        TPackage tPackage = intent.getParcelableExtra("parcel");
        HashMap<String, Channel> hashMap = tPackage.getList();
        Log.d("MyTag", "cost : " + tPackage.getCost() + " name: " + tPackage.getName()
                + " total channels: " + tPackage.getTotal_channels() + " list count: " + hashMap.size());
    }
}
```

Logcat output

```
09-13 21:57:20.578: DEBUG/MyTag(1478): cost : 10 name: hello total channels: 123 list count: 0
```

Comment: tried your code and still getting error:09-13 19:24:15.507: E/AndroidRuntime(3674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 19:24:15.507: E/AndroidRuntime(3674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value my.packs.Channel@412fcdc8
09-13 19:24:15.507: E/AndroidRuntime(3674):  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1137)
09-13 19:24:15.507: E/AndroidRuntime(3674):  at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:493)
09-13 19:24:15.507: E/AndroidRuntime(3674):  at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:477)
09-13 19:24:15.507: E/AndroidRuntime(3674):  at ...

Comment: @user461844 make sure that no fields in your object are null. I tried the above code and works fine. If you continue to get error give the error line

Comment: i've modified the code as follows :public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeInt(12);
     dest.writeString("as");
     dest.writeInt(2);
     //easiest way to transfer HashMap via parcel
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
     bundle.putSerializable("channelList", new HashMap<String, Channel>());
     dest.writeBundle(bundle);
 }               ... and getting object as null when reading.

Comment: @user461844 intent.putExtra("parcel", tPackageObject); //for sending and TPackage tpackage = intent.getParcelableExtra("parcel"); // for receiving . Have you used it like this. Also verify that the received intent is not null.

Comment: i had prevoiously used intent.putExtras(new Bundle().putParcelable("parcel", TPackage) which gives me null       and when i tried d one u provided it gives "Unfortunetely app has stopped".

Comment: @user461844 Edited the answer to show you how I tested the TPackage class. Think this will help to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need to actually put something in the createFromParcel and in writeToParcel (like the content of the object)